# Implementing Core Data with RESTKit and MagicalRecords?

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit, magicalrecord

I am trying to implement Core data for the first time . I got to know about the `MagicalRecords` and `RESTKit` while learning about the core data. i am right now in a fix about how to implement Core data and how to use both the libraries in the same application . And is it safe and best way to use both .

In `RESTKit` , it need endpoints for mapping . What if i have more then one endpoints for single Entity.

How i cam be assured that i will not have duplicate data in the application. 
Right now i am having request on each and every `UIViewController` . Fetching JSON in `UIViewController` itself and dumping it in Arrays .

How can i reduce the calls , use application without network. Please enlighten me with the knowledge about this .

Before down voting please comment what you are not understanding. Thanks

Comment: Have you read the RestKit docs about mappings, descriptors and MR? It answers a number of these questions. You offline part requires more info (and a separate question as you're asking too much here).

Comment: I have read but still confused ..

Answer (score 1):

> And is it safe and best way to use both .

Safe is all about you code and how you write it. You don't need to use MR & RK together but you can - both are conveniences to help you.

> What if i have more then one endpoints for single Entity.

Create multiple request / response descriptors

> How i cam be assured that i will not have duplicate data in the application.

Use core data and unique identities. Consider also using a shared data controller rather then redefining everything in each view controller.

> How can i reduce the calls , use application without network.

You need to design your own scheme. Core data will help as you can run fetch requests to get existing data and make a request to update, if you use a fetched results controller it will automatically update with the results.